# date format picture ends before converting entire input string in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a PD_HEAT_DATA table with HEATID and HEATDEPARTURE_ACT columns. Data type of HEATDEPARTURE column is VARCHAR2 and it holds timestamps in the format 2019-07-28 23:11:11,359.

My requirement is to retrieve the records from PD_HEAT_DATA table between 6 AM of today and 6 AM of next day.

**Sample Data:**

```
HeatID              HEATDEPARTURE_ACT    
0001024002          2019-07-29 00:46:42,115

0001024003          2019-07-29 06:46:42,115
0001024004          2019-07-29 23:46:42,115

0001024003          2019-07-30 00:06:42,115

0001024004          2019-07-30 04:46:42,115
```

I have tried following code but it is not giving desired result:

```
select heatid, HEATDEPARTURE_ACT  from hd_heat_data  where to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= trunc(sysdate
-1) + 6/24 and
      to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < trunc(sysdate) + 6/24
```

I have tried following code but it is not giving desired result:

```
select heatid, HEATDEPARTURE_ACT  from hd_heat_data  where to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= trunc(sysdate
-1) + 6/24 and
      to_date(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < trunc(sysdate) + 6/24
```

Comment: Another good example why storing date values in a VARCHAR column is a really bad idea. If you have the chance, fix the definition of the table

Answer (score 0):

You have fractional seconds at the end of your `HEATDEPARTURE_ACT` strings which you need to trim off prior to converting the string to a date:

```
select heatid, HEATDEPARTURE_ACT
  from hd_heat_data
  where TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, '[^,]*'),
                'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate-1) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
                                             AND trunc(sysdate) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc84e8a5e7279109eec6eb1aa5ab4123)

(Note that I altered the dates in the fiddle data so results would be produced)

Comment: Getting ora-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999 and not be 0

Comment: That sounds like a data issue. Verify that all the HEATDEPARTURE_ACT fields are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your format provided in `TO_TIMESTAMP` as `TO_TIMESTAMP(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF')`

```
SELECT
    HEATID,
    HEATDEPARTURE_ACT
FROM
    HD_HEAT_DATA
WHERE
    TO_TIMESTAMP(HEATDEPARTURE_ACT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF') 
    BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) +
    INTERVAL '6' HOUR - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

See the demo of reproduction of the issue and resolution, [HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4aa899795da5cc90b69899f538537a68)

Cheers!!

Comment: My mistake, Used my format of working in the example. see this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=636c3cb90acb57ecd044cba483ba39e8) -- Updated the answer, Please check!!

Comment: Getting ora-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999 and not be 0

Comment: Means there is improper data stored in a column: `HEATDEPARTURE_ACT`. You can check your data before proceeding with this query or you can edit your question and share the sample data which is causing the problem